# JUnit Fork-Mode in Java Classes

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit

There's support for `forkMode` in Ant and Maven and occasionally we use it with value `perTest`. However, the JUnit-tests in Eclipse still fail when we run the tests on a class or on a project (Run As -> JUnit Test). Obviously JUnit uses default settings or behaviour and executes the tests in parallel causing some red crosses in the JUnit-view.

1. Is there a way to code something into the test-class that lets JUnit behave like the `forkMode` setting? We don't mind if there's an Eclipse-only solution for this.
2. Or can this be done with a Run Configuration in Eclipse?

EDIT:
I understand that the problems are based on data remaining after tests and further tests will fail due to that. While this makes sense, please understand that this doesn't answer my question. Think of my situation as being part of some sort of a Tiger Team. We have a bunch of issues and fixing that part of existing tests is just one of them. Trust me, we will try to cover everything... (*I haven't heard that in a while*)

Comment: Eclipse doesn't execute tests in parallel, unless you're using a parallel runner (which isn't standard). In maven forkMode=perTest means you'll get a separate JVM for each test. The reason that your tests are failing in Eclipse is probably because you're executing all of your tests in the same JVM, so you're not cleaning your data between tests properly.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse runs the JUnit test serially, in a single thread, in the same JVM. If you have tests that normally operate in parallel, this should not affect the test behavior. However, if you assume that you can change settings in the VM, like system properties, or class static variables, and the next test will not have those changes, that will break your tests.

The rule of thumb is that each test should leave the system (vm, database, filesystem) exactly as it found it so that each test can be run at any time, in any order.