# How to use different static content in unit tests?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I' writing tests in java using JUnit. I've tried something like this (simplified):

```
public class Main() {

    static int a = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a++;
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}

public class TestA() {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Main.main(null);
    }
}

public class TestB() {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Main.main(null);
    }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    TestA.class,
    TestB.class
})
public class All { }
```

I want my test to be run with static content individual for each test. Is it possible to achieve this behaviours?

Comment: Anything that has `static` in front of it is tricky to test. You'll have a much easier time if you can change your `Main` class to not use `static`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the static state is package-private, so your test class can reset it in a `@Before` method (given it is declared in the same package).
This can be tricky for more complex state and does not solve the issue for private static state.

The only way I know of to prevent static state to spread between unit tests is having a new JVM for each test being run. Depending on your JUnit runner, it may provide a way to "fork" the JVM in different ways, achieving your desired result.

For instance, the Apache Ant JUnit runner provides an argument `forkMode` which can be set to `perTest` (see documentation https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit).
With this setting, Ant will create a JVM for Junit on each single test, effectively having independent "static states" for each test.

The Eclipse JUnit runner unfortunately does not provide such capability (see [JUnit Fork-Mode in Java Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933565/junit-fork-mode-in-java-classes)), you will have to run your tests one by one there.

That being said, if you are unable to test your software units without side effect, it might be a sign of bad design. Refactoring the tested code might be the best solution *if available*.